# AngularJS Routing not working properly with Django

Tags: angularjs, django

I know there are a ton of questions regarding AngularJS routing and trust me I've read through them all..

My issue is a weird one. Basically the routing works for one route, but none of the others.. and with the route that works I get a strange error regarding the controller that I don't know how to solve:

[image]

So the routing works for the Settings button, but when I press the English button the view does not load. And what's even weirder is if i remove the controller from the settings view, then the settings page doesn't load either..

Here's the relevant code:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CRS Client Portal</title>

  <base href="/" />

  <!-- The HTML5 Shim is required for older browsers, mainly older versions IE -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
        <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
  <![endif]-->

  {% include 'stylesheets.html' %}
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body ng-app="crsportal">
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <div class="container-fluid user-profile">
    {% include 'userprofile.html' %}
  </div>
  {% else %}
  <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="LoginController as vm">
      {% include 'login.html' %}
  </div>
  {% endif %}

  {% include 'javascripts.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

**userprofile.html**

```
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
<div class="container">
    <h1 id="languagehead">Please choose a language to get started:</h1>
    <a href="/english" class="btn btn-primary langbtn" role="button"> English</a>
    <a href="/spanish" class="btn btn-primary langbtn" role="button"> Spanish</a>
</div>

<div ng-view></div>

**app
```

.js**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('crsportal', [
      'crs.authentication',
      'crs.config',
      'crs.routes',
      'crs.profiles.controllers',
      'video.controller',
    ]);

  angular
    .module('crs.config', []);

  angular
    .module('crs.profiles.controllers', []);

  angular
    .module('crs.routes', ['ngRoute']);

  angular
    .module('video.controller', []);

  angular
    .module('crsportal')
    .run(run);

  run.$inject = ['$http'];

    /**
    * @name run
    * @desc Update xsrf $http headers to align with Django's defaults
    */
  function run($http) {
      $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
      $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    }

})();
```

**routes.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('crs.routes')
        .config(config);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

    /**
     * @name config
     * @desc Define valid application routes
     */
    function config($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/home', {
         templateURL: 'static/templates/home.html'
      }).when('/english', {
         templateURL:'static/templates/test.html',
         controller: 'VideoController',
         controllerAs: 'vm'
      }).when('/spanish', {
         templateURL:'static/templates/spanish.html'
      }).when('/:username/settings', {
         templateUrl: 'static/templates/settings.html',
         controller: 'ProfileSettingsController',
         controllerAs: 'vm'
      }).when('/english/:title', {
         templateUrl: 'static/templates/video.html'
      }).otherwise('/home');
    }
})();
```

**profile-settings.controller.js**

```
/**
* ProfileSettingsController
* @namespace crs.profiles.controllers
*/
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('crs.profiles.controllers')
    .controller('ProfileSettingsController', ProfileSettingsController);

  ProfileSettingsController.$inject = [
    '$location', '$routeParams', 'Authentication', 'Profile', 'Snackbar'
  ];

  /**
  * @namespace ProfileSettingsController
  */
  function ProfileSettingsController($location, $routeParams, Authentication, Profile, Snackbar) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.destroy = destroy;
    vm.update = update;

    activate();


    /**
    * @name activate
    * @desc Actions to be performed when this controller is instantiated.
    * @memberOf thinkster.profiles.controllers.ProfileSettingsController
    */
    function activate() {
      var authenticatedAccount = Authentication.getAuthenticatedAccount();
      var username = $routeParams.username.substr(1);

      // Redirect if not logged in
      if (!authenticatedAccount) {
        $location.url('/');
        Snackbar.error('You are not authorized to view this page.');
      } else {
        // Redirect if logged in, but not the owner of this profile.
        if (authenticatedAccount.username !== username) {
          $location.url('/');
          Snackbar.error('You are not authorized to view this page.');
        }
      }

      Profile.get(username).then(profileSuccessFn, profileErrorFn);

      /**
      * @name profileSuccessFn
      * @desc Update `profile` for view
      */
      function profileSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
        vm.profile = data.data;
        $location.url('/home');
      }

      /**
      * @name profileErrorFn
      * @desc Redirect to index
      */
      function profileErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
        $location.url('/');
        Snackbar.error('That user does not exist.');
      }
    }


    /**
    * @name destroy
    * @desc Destroy this user's profile
    * @memberOf thinkster.profiles.controllers.ProfileSettingsController
    */
    function destroy() {
      Profile.destroy(vm.profile.username).then(profileSuccessFn, profileErrorFn);

      /**
      * @name profileSuccessFn
      * @desc Redirect to index and display success snackbar
      */
      function profileSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
        Authentication.unauthenticate();
        window.location = '/';

        Snackbar.show('Your account has been deleted.');
      }


      /**
      * @name profileErrorFn
      * @desc Display error snackbar
      */
      function profileErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
        Snackbar.error(data.error);
      }
    }


    /**
    * @name update
    * @desc Update this user's profile
    * @memberOf thinkster.profiles.controllers.ProfileSettingsController
    */
    function update() {
      Profile.update(vm.profile).then(profileSuccessFn, profileErrorFn);

      /**
      * @name profileSuccessFn
      * @desc Show success snackbar
      */
      function profileSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
        Snackbar.show('Your profile has been updated.');
      }


      /**
      * @name profileErrorFn
      * @desc Show error snackbar
      */
      function profileErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
        Snackbar.error(data.error);
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Where have you defined the `Profile` provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error message is telling you exactly what's wrong:

> Unknown provider: ProfileProvider <- Profile <-
>   ProfileSettingsController

Your `ProfileSettingsController` is injecting `Profile`, which doesn't appear to exist, it doesn't exist in your provided javascript either.

I would suggest checking through your code and making sure you have the Profile factory/service actually defined.

Comment: Right, come to find out I made a typo when defining it. So now that error is fixed but I am still having the issue where the routing isn't working

Comment: If my solution fixed your problem, you'll need to mark it as correct and post another question with your next problem, we can't just keep fixing your issues in the comment sections.

Comment: your solution fixed part of the problem. the original question mainly pertained to the routing not working, I thought the error message was relevant to that issue. but I get it, you want the reputation points and what not... thanks for the help Shannon. Hopefully you can answer my next post :)

Comment: hey @JamesBrace, it's not just that, if someone comes here looking for an issue with routing, it all comes down to your original post that has nothing to do with routing it self but a typo in a provider name, so it's not going to help people if they have to read through comments to get their desired answer :)